# How to redirect dynamic pages with htaccess

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have some old indexed pages like:

index.php?action=addon_googlemap_showmap&listingID=XXXXX&popup=1

index.php?action=addon_googlemap_showmap&listingID=XXXXX&popup=yes

and I want to redirect them to new urls:

index.php?action=listingview&listingID=XXXXX

XXXXX is a number.

What should I put in my htaccess file?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

mod_rewrite is not worth the headaches (especially in .htaccess).

I would strongly recommend you put a redirect in your index.php instead. Something like

```
<?php
if ($_GET['action'] == 'addon_googlemap_showmap') {
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location: http://...../index.php?action=listingview&listingID=" . $_GET['listingID']);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Awesome Artelius. I was with the same problem. I changed the "if" for "switch" ("case", "break") and "$_GET" for "($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])". My doubt is, is this the best method to permanently redirect my pages?